# Problem communicating with multiple ROS units: rostopic list is visible but not rostopic echo. ($ROS_IP is already set)

Tags: ros-melodic, communication, multiple

I am communicating with my desktop PC as master and my Raspberry pi as slave.
When I start a node on the Raspberry pi and publish a topic (`/scan`), the desktop PC shows the topic (`/scan`) in the `rostopic list` but `no new messages` in the `rostopic hz /scan`.

The conditions are as follows

`<Desktop PC: ubuntu 18.04 / melodic`

Contents of `~/.bashrc`:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.30.109:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.30.109
export ROS_IP=192.168.30.109
```

`<Raspberry pi: ubuntu18.04 / melodic>`

Contents of ~/.bashrc

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.30.109:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.30.110
export ROS_IP=192.168.30.110
```

Note that I tried deleting ROS_HOSTNAME, but it did not work.

Also, I don't know if this information is necessary, but when I do `rqt_graph`, `Nodes/Topics(all)` shows both /scan and the node that is publishing, but `Nodes/Topics(active)` shows only `/rostopic`

****************** only appears.

Please let me know if there is anything else I should check.

I am a Japanese speaker, so there may be some things I am not doing well.
Thank you in advance for your answer.

11/23 23:40(@UTC) added

I typed the following commands on both my desktop PC and Raspberry pi.

```
sudo ufw allow 11311
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw reload
```

I am aware that 11311 is the port used for ROS communication and 22 is the port used for ssh.

11/24 2:20(@UTC) added

**I solved the problem by typing the following command on both my desktop PC and Raspberry pi!**

```
sudo ufw allow 1024:65535/tcp
sudo ufw reload
```

Thank you so much to ignacio and Mike973 for your comments and answers.

I may come back to ask again, so please help me again if you like.

Comment: are you sure those are your system IPs? Maybe they are dynamically set for you and from time to time they change

Comment: Please edit your post to describe what changes you have made to the firewall on each machine.

Comment: Also, if you set ROS_IP you should NOT set ROS_HOSTNAME. But this is not the cause of your difficulty.

Comment: Dear ignacio
Thank you for your comment.
The IP address is the one I checked with $ifconfig, I have been checking it for a week and it has not changed.

Comment: Dear Mike973.
I have added a note that I have changed it in the firefall configuration.
Please check it.
I also understood that when setting ROS_IP, ROS_HOSTNAME should not be set. I will change it just in case.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firewall changes are not sufficient to allow ros1 to work. ros1 requires that you allow incoming tcp connections to all port numbers >= 1024 from the other host.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, so I solved it by typing the following command on both my desktop PC and Raspberry pi!
Thank you very much for your answer.
    
[sudo ufw allow 1024:65535/tcp]
[sudo ufw reload]

Comment: This is not the preferred way to handle this problem, unless you trust every other computer on your network. Please use the ufw `from a.b.c.d` syntax to reduce the exposure to only the hosts you need to allow.